# Some op-amps are marked for audio applications, what makes them diferent from "regular opamps"?

Tags: operational-amplifier, audio

Datasheets for opamps for audio applications contain many example circuits that have nothing to do with audio applications at all. But anyway, what makes an Audio Op-Amp an Audio Op-Amp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Audio amplifiers have usually a very low total harmonic distortion (THD) and also a very low noise level. And other specs like power supply rejection and common-mode rejection are very high to keep the overall signal quality at a high level.

Comment: Also, a respectable slew rate.

Answer (score 3):

*What makes them different*

In my opinion: **nothing**. An opamp cannot tell the difference between an audio signal or any other signal in the audio frequency range.

What is true that some opamps, for example, due to their lower noise or supply voltage range, are **more suitable for using in audio equipment**. But it's still just an opamp and not for audio only.

For example the popular NE5532 has:

- low noise
- low output impedance (to drive 600 ohm load)
- can operate on +/- 15 V supply (often used in audio)
- high commonmode rejection

But it is indeed suitable for many other applications. It was not even designed with only specifically audio applications in mind.

And regarding distortion: feedback is used to keep distortion low, it's not a specific property of the opamp itself. It cannot be because the voltage gain is too high to make it linear.

Comment: Yes, operational amplifiers have indeed distortion which is _masked_ by the feedback. The open loop gain will however vary with frequency and other things, but because it's less than infinite, the distortion will eventually show up. Sometimes the distortion doesn't matter, but in an audio application it does, so an "audio opamp" will minimize things like internal crossover-distortion.

Comment: I would not say that the distortion is *masked*, it is actively  suppressed by the feedback loop. By how much depends indeed on how much "surplus gain" is available.